# Hashicorp vault fail to initialize

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When bootstrapping vault ASG on a server dedicated for terraform deployment. When the init script runs, the exit status of `vault_seal_status=$(curl -s $${NEW_VAULT_ADDR}/v1/sys/seal-status)` is 6. Kept trying for 100 times with sleep period 15s between each, didn't see any changes.

Inside vault ec2, tried the following:

1. `export VAULT_ADDR=https://localhost:8200`
2. `curl -s https://localhost:8200/v1/sys/seal-status | jq -r`

**get response**

```
{ "type": "awskms",
 "initialized": false,
 "sealed": true,
 "t": 0,
 "n": 0,
 "progress": 0,
 "nonce": "",
 "version": "",
 "migration": false,
 "recovery_seal": true,
 "storage_type": "consul"
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with Vault, but with your connectivity to it. Where are you running your first command from? And what is the output of using `curl -v` for that request?

Comment: The first command is part of the init command running on a deployment server, which lives in another AWS account. It will gain access to another AWS account where the vault ASG lives by assuming a role.

Comment: `curl -v` says the host for vault fqdn cannot be resolved

Comment: Well there's your problem - the hostname you're using can't be resolved from where you're making that call. You need to either use an IP address or set up a DNS entry for it in Route 53

Comment: Right, so I checked again. I have the CNAME set up in Route53 and the load balancer is connected to the ec2 instances (all in Service). What else could be wrong?

Comment: BTW, the DNS name of the LB can be resolved. However, the alias cannot.

Comment: It was an issue with VPC association, resolved now.